# Нужна ли запятая после "мне"?

Tags: пунктуация

Более подробную информацию обо мне Вы найдете в прикрепленном резюме.

Comment: Избегайте ненамеренной рифмы. Лучше так: «Более подробную информацию Вы найдете в моём резюме».

Answer (score 1):

**Запятая не нужна**. Это обычное простое предложение. Его можно улучшить. Обычно в таких случаях употребляют слово *прилагаемый*, а не *прикрепленный*. Тот факт, что "обо мне" рифмуется с "резюме" делает предложение смешным, а это неуместно, если речь идет о поисках работы (если вы не профессиональный юморист, конечно).
Обращение *Вы*, написанное с заглавной буквы, уместно, если вы адресуете свое письмо конкретному человеку (например, начальнику отдела кадров). Лучше избегать таких обращений в официальных письмах. Незачем употреблять слова "обо мне": и так ясно, что Вы о себе говорите. Рассмотрите, например, такие варианты:

**Более подробная информация — в прилагаемом резюме.**

**Прилагаю подробное резюме.**

**Подробное резюме прилагается.**